# Cannot convert traditional for loop to for-each loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

For some inexplicable reason, I cannot convert this loop into a more natural `for (var player in fizzPlayers) { ... }` loop:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < fizzPlayers.length; i++) {
    var player = fizzPlayers[i];
    var val = parseInt(player.value);
    if (val != 0) {
      active.push(player);
      actfact.push(parseInt(player.value));
      actname.push(capitaliseFirstLetter(player.id));
    }
  }
```

I want to write this the more natural for-each way, like this:

```
  for (var player in fizzPlayers) {
    var val = parseInt(player.value);
    if (val != 0) {
      active.push(player);
      actfact.push(parseInt(player.value));
      actname.push(capitaliseFirstLetter(player.id));
    }
  }
```

But it doesn't work, as you can see in the runnable code snippet at the bottom.

For debugging, I inserted this code right before the loop:

```
  // prints undefined... but why?
  for (var player in fizzPlayers) {
    console.log(player.value);
  }
```

It prints `undefined` for the 5 players. Why? There is a similar loop earlier in the program where the `for (var player in fizzPlayers) { ... }` loop is working just fine.

Why is this happening? What am I missing?

```js
var fizzLoaded = false;
var fizzDiv, fizzFrom, fizzTo, fizzPlayers;

function fizzLoad() {
  if (fizzLoaded) {
    return;
  }
  fizzLoaded = true;
  var fizzForm = document.getElementById('fizzbuzz');
  fizzFrom = document.getElementById('rangeFrom');
  fizzTo = document.getElementById('rangeTo');
  fizzPlayers = [
    document.getElementById('frodo'),
    document.getElementById('sam'),
    document.getElementById('merry'),
    document.getElementById('pippin'),
    document.getElementById('bilbo')
  ];
  fizzDiv = document.getElementById('fizzOut');
}

function restrictRange() {
  var rFrom = parseInt(fizzFrom.value);
  var rTo = parseInt(fizzTo.value);
  fizzTo.min = rFrom;
  fizzFrom.max = rTo;
}

function validateValues() {
  var rFrom = parseInt(fizzFrom.value);
  var rTo = parseInt(fizzTo.value);
  if (rTo < rFrom) {
    alert("Illegal range from " + rFrom + " to " + rTo);
    return false;
  }
  for (var player in fizzPlayers) {
    var val = parseInt(player.value);
    if (val < 0 || val > 100) {
      alert("Illegal value " + val + " for player " + player.id);
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

function capitaliseFirstLetter(string) {
      return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}

function fizzing() {
  fizzLoad();
  restrictRange();
  if (!validateValues()) {
    fizzDiv.innerHTML = "Illegal inputs";
    return;
  }

  var table = "";
  var rFrom = parseInt(fizzFrom.value);
  var rTo = parseInt(fizzTo.value);
  var active = [];
  var actfact = [];
  var actname = [];

  // prints undefined... but why?
  for (var player in fizzPlayers) {
    console.log(player.value);
  }

  for (var player in fizzPlayers) {
    var val = parseInt(player.value);
    if (val != 0) {
      active.push(player);
      actfact.push(parseInt(player.value));
      actname.push(capitaliseFirstLetter(player.id));
    }
  }

  table += "<table>\n";
  table += "  <tr><th>Value</th><th>Message</th></tr>\n";
  for (var i = rFrom; i <= rTo; i++) {

    var msg = "";
    for (var p = 0; p < active.length; p++) {
      if (i % actfact[p] == 0) {
        msg += actname[p];
      }
    }
    if (msg == "") {
      msg = "" + i;
    }
    table += "  <tr><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + msg + "</td></tr>\n";
  }
  table += "</table>\n";

  fizzDiv.innerHTML = table;
}
```

```css
h1 {
    clear: left;
}

hr {
    clear: left;
}

label {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: left;
}
input {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  padding-left:10px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>FizzBuzz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fizzbuzz.css">
    <script src="fizzbuzz.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Config</h1>
    <form id="fizzbuzz">
      <fieldset id="fizzControl" oninput="fizzing();">
        <label>Range From<input id="rangeFrom" type="number" min="1" max="100" value="1" required></label>
        <label>Range To<input id="rangeTo"   type="number" min="1" max="1024" value="100" required></label>
        <div id="players" >
          <label>Frodo<input id="frodo" type="number" min="0" max="100" value="3" required></label>
          <label>Sam<input id="sam" type="number" min="0" max="100" value="5" required></label>
          <label>Merry<input id="merry" type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0" required></label>
          <label>Pippin<input id="pippin" type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0" required></label>
          <label>Bilbo<input id="bilbo" type="number" min="0" max="100" value="0" required></label>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
    <hr>
    <h1>Output</h1>
    <div id="fizzOut" >Change a value to get output (a snippet thing)</div>
    <script>fizzing();</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Right, a `for..in` loop is not the same as a regular `for` loop. You shouldn't use `for..in` to loop arrays.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The idiomatic way to write a loop that iterates over Array elements is `forEach`. As comments have noted, `for... in` is for Object keys, not Array elements.

```
fizzPlayers.forEach(function(player) {
  var val = parseInt(player.value);
  if (val != 0) {
    active.push(player);
    actfact.push(parseInt(player.value));
    actname.push(capitaliseFirstLetter(player.id));
  }
});
```

You can `Array.prototype.forEach` in [all modern browsers (IE9 +)](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Array.prototype.forEach).

[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Thanks, this is very informative! Do you have a link to the right docs on this topic?

Comment: MDN is a good source for JavaScript docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach.

Comment: Thanks, please edit that into your answer, it will be easier to read for everyone that way. And btw, how come the `for...in` loop work seems to work fine in the `validateValues` function?

Comment: `player` refers to each element's index in the array, say `0`. A number doesn't have a `value` property, so `player.value` is `undefined`. `parseInt(undefined)` is `NaN`, which is neither less than 0 nor greater than 100.

Answer (score 4):

Check what is actually being assigned to `player`:

```
> fizzPlayers = ["jim", "bob", "joe"]
> for (var player in fizzPlayers) {
    console.log(player);
  }
0
1
2
```

Iterating through an object gives you the *keys*. The keys of an array are the indices. In this case you are better off using a regular for loop rather than this for-each loop, since if you have assigned any other properties to the array (like `fizzPlayers.barg = 40;`) the for-each loop will give you those property names as well

---

However, if you are using jQuery, you can use [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/):

```
> $.each(fizzPlayers, function (index, player) { 
    console.log(index + ": " + player); 
  });
0: jim
1: bob
2: joe
```

Note that the callback takes two parameters: the index, and the value.

Answer (score 3):

In Javascript, the `for-each` loop assigns the *index* to the control variable, so you would need to use `fizzPlayers[player]` instead of just `player`.  You might not like it (I often don't), but that's how it works.

Answer (score 2):

You need

```
for (var p in fizzPlayers) {
    console.log(fizzPlayers[p].value);
}
```

This is a common annoyance.  An [ECMAScript 6 proposal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) has

```
for (var player of fizzPlayers) {
    console.log(player.value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `for in` loop in `JavaScript` runs through the enumerable properties of an object. Hence, you can't convert it to a classic `for` loop. More formally, from the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

> A for...in loop only iterates over enumerable properties. Objects
>   created from built–in constructors like Array and Object have
>   inherited non–enumerable properties from Object.prototype and
>   String.prototype, such as String's indexOf() method or Object's
>   toString() method. The loop will iterate over all enumerable
>   properties of the object itself and those the object inherits from its
>   constructor's prototype (properties closer to the object in the
>   prototype chain override prototypes' properties).

Answer (score 1):

The for-each loop assigns the index

```
// prints undefined... but why?
for (var playerIndex in fizzPlayers) {
   console.log(fizzPlayers[playerIndex].value);
}
```

You could consider a convenience library like [lo-dash](https://lodash.com/docs#forEach) for utility functions.